# Rotation matrix sending the North pole to a specified point on the sphere

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

I was wondering if there is a simple formula for the 3 by 3 rotation matrix sending the North pole to a specified point on the sphere, whose coordinate is given by the spherical coordinate ($\theta$, $\phi$).

Edit: I realized that the answer is not a single matrix but rather a one-parameter set of matrices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by the North Pole You mean vector $(0,0,1)^T$. Notice that there are a lot of such rotations, because we can always begin with rotation that fixes the North pole and then apply our rotation. The rotation around $OZ$ axis is given by the matrix
$$R_z(\theta)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Rotation around $OX$ axis is given by
$$R_x(\theta)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\\
0 & \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Now we can do the following: first apply arbitrary rotation $R_z(\psi)$, then apply $R_x(\phi)$ to move the North pole to $(0, \phi)$, and then apply $R_z(\theta)$ which moves $(0, \phi)$ to $(\theta, \phi)$ as desired. So the complete answer would be
$$R_z(\theta)R_x(\phi)R_z(\psi)$$

Comment: This is great! But isn't it $\phi$ instead of $\pi/2 - \phi$ ?

Comment: @a12345 The angle between vector $(0,0,1)^T$ and XY plane is $\frac\pi2$, so we need to rotate by $\frac\pi2 - \phi$ in order to get the angle $\phi$

Comment: Maybe we are thinking about different things, but I think the angle $\phi$ is measured from the Z-axis so that the North pole has the coordinate (0,0)

Comment: @a12345 ok, then you're correct. I'm changing answer

Comment: What is $\psi$ supposed to mean here?